# How to get sqlalchemy to catch pymssql exceptions on network outage

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymssql

Unfortunately, I can't post my full code here due to corporate restrictions (also why I'm using pymssql...), but here is the essence of my problem:

I'm using sqlalchemy (version 1.4.42) in Python 3.10.5 on Windows 10 with "mssql+pymssql" in the engine connect string.  Everything is working fine under normal conditions.

At one point, I'm deliberately dropping the network to simulate an outage.  During the cursor.execute(), I'm getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 458, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1086, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1117, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1250, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1788, in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1834, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')
```

What is unexpected here is that I'm getting a pymssql exception, and not an SQLAlchemy exception.  Sure, I *can* import pymssql and handle this exception, but I shouldn't have to, should I?  Isn't that the point of my using SQLAlchemy?

Have I missed something here, or did I just find a weird edge case?

Comment: SQLA generally wraps such errors in a SQLAlchemy exception.  Try calling `type(...)` on the exception object - it's probably something like `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb It's not.  That's the problem.  It's reporting as the pymssql type.  I've got a block to catch OperationalErrors, and it's not dropping into that.  It's very odd, because I completely expected the exception to be wrapped.

Comment: @PhantomofKrankor Did you ever solve this? :\

Comment: @jtlz2 Unfortunately, I don't have access to that code anymore.  IIRC, I never did get a truly satisfactory solution because the actual exception was being swallowed up by sqlalchemy.  I think I just had to handle the exception in a generic fashion, and hope that I don't have too much work repeated in the case of sometime less disastrous than a network outage.

Comment: I tried pytds and it worked well!